# How to prevent non-touch phones to see application in Android Market

Tags: android

I thought this would be an easy one but I was wrong...

My app won't work on non-touch android devices so I don't want it to show up in market for these.

I hoped to find a property to set in AndroidManifest.xml but the closest match I can find is this:

```
android:reqTouchScreen

The type of touch screen the application requires, if any at all. The value must be one of the following strings: 

Value   Description
"undefined" The application doesn't require a touch screen. (The touch screen requirement is undefined.) This is the default value.
"notouch"   The application doesn't require a touch screen.
"stylus"    The application requires a touch screen that's operated with a stylus.
"finger"    The application requires a touch screen that can be operated with a finger.
```

So what I would like to do is set reqTouchScreen to both stylus and finger, which isn't allowed. Or, a simple reqTouchScreen=yes would be nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-configuration-element.html) you copy-and-pasted from tells you, use two `<uses-configuration>` elements.

Comment: @Eby: not at this time that I am aware of. The Android Market presently requires devices to have a touchscreen. That restriction may be lifted with the advent of Google TV, though -- we will have to see.